# How to stop FFMPEG processing when first of two inputs end?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I want to do an SSIM comparison of an encoded clip VS a reference file

I have clips of unknown duration that share the same content as a known good source.  These clips always start from the beginning of the content but variably end (i.e some have a duration of 30 seconds, others 33).

I tried using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mov -i reference_file.mp4 -lavfi  "ssim" -f null -
```

But the processing will only terminate when the duration of `reference_file.mp4` has elapsed, therefore skewing the SSIM results.

How do I make the SSIM processing stop when the duration of `clip.mov` if I do not know the duration of `clip.mov` beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssim supports the shortest option

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mov -i reference_file.mp4 -lavfi  "ssim=shortest=1" -f null -
```